# Pentaho server is not accessible

Tags: pentaho

I am using pentaho 4.5 , but whenever i install it and try to access the server , it raises some issue like JVM_bind , but i am not running any server ,
recently i changed my tomcat port no , then it raises this issue

```
Pentaho Initialization Exception


The following errors were detected
The system failed to initialize.
   SolutionEngine.ERROR_1009 - Missing, invalid, or expired product license.

Please see the server console for more details on each error detected.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hussain, it looks like your license has expired.  If you are an Enterprise customer, you may need to install (or re-install) your license files using the Enterprise Console.  If you have not subscribed, your demo license may have expired.

Comment: thanx man , it is solved , i also realised the same prob , took a new licence and it is solved

Comment: how you got neew liscence

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure did is help but did you change pentaho-solution to other version ?